# I initialized a value inside $.post but cannot access it outside $.post

Tags: jquery, post

The following is my code:

```
$.post(
    "index.php?component=static_content&action=rules_count", 
    { region:rname,page_url:page_url},
    function(data1) {
        alert(data1);
        var num = $(data1).find('.ruleNum').html();
    }
);
alert(num);
```

But on line `alert(num);` there is an error `num is undefined`. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you declared the variable `num` inside your post callback, so outside that function the variable is clearly undefined

But even if you define it outside, its value won't be displayed as you expected, since ajax is asynchronous (so that, when you alert the variable the ajax call is still running)

if you need to acces num even outside just call another function passing the variable, e.g.

```
$.post(
    "index.php?component=static_content&action=rules_count", 
    { region:rname,page_url:page_url},
    function(data1) {
        alert(data1);
        continueProcess(data1);
    }
});

var continueProcess = function(num) {
   alert(num);
}
```

or use `Deferred Objects` (since ajax methods return a promise since `jQuery 1.5`) you can also do

```
$.when($.post(...).done(function(num) {
   alert(num)
});
```

Comment: if someone explain the downvote, I could improve my answer (and myself)

Answer (score 1):

`num` is a local variable in the anonymous function passed to `$.post()`. It does not exist beyond the function's scope, yet you're accessing it from a totally different scope.

Aside from that, the variable will be defined at a later time, not when you're using it. If it was a global variable, it still wouldn't be available, at the time you're using it, because it would only be defined *after* the POST operation finishes.

Therefore, you can only use `num` inside that function. Here's an example of what you could do:

```
function numWasReceived(num) {
    alert(num);
}

$.post(
    "index.php?component=static_content&action=rules_count", 
    { region:rname,page_url:page_url},
    function(data1) {
        alert(data1);
        var num = $(data1).find('.ruleNum').html();
        numWasReceived(num);
    }
);
```

Comment: In addition it should be kept in mind, that `$.post` is asynchrounous.

Comment: so what can i do to take that value outside?

Comment: @guitarlass, this is an asynchronous operation, so whatever you do, you still need to run some code in asynchronous fashion. That's because the code that you run after you call `$.post` will happen *before* POST finished executing. Think about it like this: you send the POST request, then you can immediately do something else. In the mean time, the POST request executes. At some point in the future, the POST request finishes. This is the time you need to use what the POST request returned.

Comment: @guitarlass you can also use Deferred objects, since jQuery 1.5

Answer (score 0):

Since you declared `num` only in `$.post()` it's not available in the global scope.

Here is an in depth explanation of functions and scopes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope